# which password hash algorithm uses "password-hash:passwort default" in PHP

Tags: php, hash, passwords

Short Question:

Which algorithm uses the PHP method: password_hash("xxx", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

Has this a closer name like md5 or sha512 or is this an own algorithm with the name PASSWORD_DEFAULT?

For an exam I need to know this, but I didn't found anything to this on the World Wide Web

Comment: `$2y` is bcrypt

Comment: Did you look at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php? `PASSWORD_DEFAULT - Use the bcrypt algorithm (default as of PHP 5.5.0). Note that this constant is designed to change over time as new and stronger algorithms are added to PHP.`

Answer (score 1):

It's documented in the [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/password.constants.php)

It can change with new PHP versions. Currently it is `PASSWORD_BCRYPT` (since PHP 5.5.0). The hash will include the algorithm for `password_verify()`. It allows you to implement password storage that will update to newer (and more secure algorithms) automatically.

- On account create or password change use `password_hash()` with `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` to create the password hash.
- On sign in use `password_verify()`.
- After successful sign in check with `password_needs_rehash()` and update the hash using the password the user just provided.